# listener for keypress not working while click is applicable only on vuetify for vDialog

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am returnee for vuetify and there is an function I want to use. The function is when I press enter the dialog must be true at the `data` also when I click the button.

when I read the docs in vue there is a `v-on:keypress` which listens for key codes. And when you combined with click and keypress the code is `v-on:click.enter`( [see docs for event listeners in vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)). I use this function for my `v-dialog` to emit the `v-model` for dialog to turn true.

but the thing is that the code don't work when I use the key `enter`, it only emits when I click the button.

Is this a bug for vuetify or any suggestions for the code.

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not keyup.enter ? I tried to find click.enter in the docs with no results.

Comment: @AdrianA is right, you have to use `keyup.enter`. It it also important where you add this event listener. In your case you should add it directly to the `v-dialog` component, also add the normal `@click` event to the button